# margin-bottom works in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css

`div` is hidden on the right. When a button is clicked, `div` slides in to the left and becomes visible. `margin-bottom` (it is for leaving a gap: I do not want the bottom of the `div` to touch the edge on mobile phones) works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Why?

```
.menu-hidden
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    right: -255px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    width: 205px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu-visible
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: html code please

Comment: please provide an image